# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

I know there are lot of questions with the same tag. But I tried few solutions of them and it didn't worked. Following is my code and I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
<script>
function setPrice(){
    var price = $(".variation_select option:selected").attr("data-price")
    var sale_price = $(".variation_select option:selected").attr("data-sale-price")
    if (sale_price != "" && sale_price != "None" && sale_price != null ) {
    $("#price").html("<h3>" + sale_price + " <small class='og-price'>" + price  + "</small></h3>");
    } else {
    $("#price").html(price);
    }
}
setPrice()

$(".variation_select").change(function(){
    setPrice()

})

$("#submit-btn").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = $("#add-form").serialize();
    console.log(formData);
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: "{% url 'cart' %}",
        data: formData,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function(response, error){
            console.log(response)
            console.log(error)
        }
    })

    // $("#add-form").submit()
})

</script>
```

Error it shows on browser inspect elements is at

```
var price = $(".variation_select option:selected").attr("data-price")
```

Even though I don't think its necessary but following is the HTML code:

```
<div class='col-sm-4'>

<form id='add-form' method='GET' action="{% url 'cart' %}">
<p id='jquery-message' class='lead'>

</p>
    {% if object.variation_set.count > 1 %}
    <h3 id='price'>{{ object.variation_set.first.price }}</h3>

        <select name='item' class='form-control variation_select'>
        {% for vari_obj in object.variation_set.all %}
        <!-- <option data-img="http://www.spirit1059.com/pics/Feeds/Articles/2015611/118317/Beach.jpg" data-price="{{ vari_obj.price }}" value="{{ vari_obj.id }}">{{ vari_obj }}</option> -->
        <option  data-sale-price="{{ vari_obj.sale_price }}" data-price="{{ vari_obj.price }}" value="{{ vari_obj.id }}">{{ vari_obj }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        </select>

    {% else %}
            <input type="hidden" name='item' value='{{ object.variation_set.first.id }}' />
            <h3 id='price'>{% if object.variation_set.first.sale_price %}
            {{ object.variation_set.first.sale_price  }}
            <small class='og-price'>{{ object.variation_set.first.price }}</small>
            {% else %}
            {{ object.variation_set.first.price }}
            {% endif %}
        </h3>


    {% endif %}
    <br/>
    <input class='form-control' type='number' name='qty' value='1' />
<br/>
<input id='submit-btn' type='submit' value='Add to Cart' class='btn btn-default' />
</form>
```

Jquery Script file includes following:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js' %}"></script>
```

Please ignore Django template language if you are not familiar with it. You can still have the idea about jQuery error skipping the template language.

Comment: is jquery script included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

1. add jQuery script before your JS code

   ```
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. define variable "$". You can achieve this by adding a wrapper to your JS code:

   ```
   <script>
       (function($){
           // your code here
       })(jQuery)
   </script>
   ```

Comment: Now it says Jquery is not defined.

Comment: @Alikhan check step one, make sure you added `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>` BEFORE your JS code

Answer (score 3):

after using jquery script, use this code instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     setPrice()
     $(".variation_select").change(function(){
         setPrice()
     })
});
```

Comment: This is already included in base file. In Django I use template inheritance which means I have to declare $(document).ready(function() in the main script file and to all other files I only will have to write the code by rendering base decoration as default and my jquery code for file as addition to default.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery in your page you need to include a jquery liberary in your html page. Because initially in javascript `$` is nothing but `$` means jquery which tells the browser that its a jquery function.

Include this jquery liberary in your webpage.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the script could be included but a conflict may cause the problem right?

Comment: what kind of conflict?

Comment: some other script using `$` maybe we dont know

Comment: yeah but we cant predict that..if the error comes then we can see where is the erorr

Answer (score 0):

MMh try including jquery before your  tag

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did both but error won't go away. I was following previously solved questions. However it will work fine if I remove $. But then the function will be effected. I am updating my jquery script in question.

Comment: IF you remove the $ function (that is a shortcut for calling the jQuery function) your code change meaning. You should really undertand better what you are doing here ;)